# int validation fails on empty TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding, idataerrorinfo

I've a `TextBox` bound to an `int` property with `[Required]` and `[Range(1, 5)]`attribute, when app starts `TextBox` gets `0`, if I press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and delete that 0, I get this message in Debug log:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=Order.PartyCode; DataItem='OrderVM' (HashCode=66572856); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at MS.Internal.Data.SystemConvertConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

and validation doesn't work. I get same error if I use `Nullable<int>` instead of `int`!

Is it a must to have `string` properties to work with `TextBox` or there's way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by using `TargetNullValue` in your binding, like so:
`<TextBox Text="{Binding Test, TargetNullValue=''}"/>`

This sets `TargetNullValue` to an empty string, which tells the binding that an empty string should be converted to `null` for the binding source.

If you're using a normal `int`, the result is that your property will not get set at all when the text is changed to an empty string. If you're using `int?` then your property will be set to `null` when the text changes to an empty string.

Comment: I don't know why does this accept negative values as valid inputs. Without that `argetNullValue=''` validation works perfectly except for the case of empty textbox.

Answer (score 1):

While Keith's answer will probably solve the problem at hand, the fact that user could type anything in a textbox, still poses a validation issue. A string type variable is much safer for `TextBox.Text` binding.

If you want to bind with an int property, there are other controls that might be more appropriate. Since your validation rule only allows int values between 1 and 5, a `Slider`, a `ComboBox` or even a set of `RadioButton`s would be a better approach.

If you're bent on using a `TextBox`, handle `KeyDown` event to prevent user from entering non-numeric keys.

Comment: probably the best way is to extend the `TextBox` class and implement that `KeyDown` handler once there and use that extended `TextBox` wherever needed, right?

Comment: @EmonHaque: As a generic solution, you are right. In his specific situation this might not be need (he's got just 5 valid values, integers from 1 to 5). Also worth mentioning that the thing you're suggesting has already been implemented by WPF Toolkit project.